# win api sendkeys doesn't work on a specific programm

Tags: vb.net

I want to send a leftbutton-mouseclick to a (specific) program but it doesn't work. when i tried my code on several other apps it worked without any major changes.

this is my Declaration:

```
Public Class Win32
#Region "Methods And Functions Declaration"
Public Declare Function FindWindow Lib "user32.dll" Alias "FindWindowA" (ByVal IpClassName As String, ByVal IpWindowName As String) As Int32
Public Declare Function SetForegroundWindow Lib "user32.dll" (ByVal hwnd As Int32) As Int32
Public Declare Function FindWindowEx Lib "user32.dll" Alias "FindWindowExA" (ByVal hWnd1 As Int32, ByVal hWnd2 As Int32, ByVal lpsz1 As String, ByVal lpsz2 As String) As Int32
Public Declare Function EnumChildWindows Lib "user32.dll" (ByVal hWndParent As Int32, ByVal lpEnumFunc As Int32, ByVal lParam As Int32) As Int32
Public Declare Function SendMessage Lib "user32.dll" Alias "SendMessageA" (ByVal hwnd As Int32, ByVal wMsg As Int32, ByVal wParam As Int32, ByRef lParam As Int32) As Int32
Public Declare Function SendMessage Lib "user32.dll" Alias "SendMessageA" (ByVal hwnd As Int32, ByVal wMsg As Int32, ByVal wParam As Int32, ByRef lParam As String) As Int32

#End Region


#Region "Messages"
Public Const BM_CLICK As Int32 = &HF5
Public Const WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN As Int32 = &HA1
Public Const WM_NCHITTEST As Int32 = &H84
Public Const WM_NCLBUTTONDBLCLK As Int32 = &HA3
Public Const WM_NCLBUTTONUP As Int32 = &HA2
Public Const WM_SETFOCUS As Long = &H7
Public Const WM_SETTEXT As Long = &HC
Public Const WM_NCRBUTTONDOWN As Int32 = &HA4


#End Region
```

the actual code:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    'Druck Eingeben
    Dim Hwnd As Integer = Win32.FindWindow(Nothing, "V1.22 BMTS Prüfstand 2")

    If (Not Hwnd = 0) Then
        Dim HwndInfo As Integer = Win32.FindWindowEx(Hwnd, Nothing, "TGroupBox", "Info")
        If Not HwndInfo = 0 Then
            Dim ccHwnd As Integer = Win32.FindWindowEx(HwndInfo, Nothing, "TPanel", Nothing)
            If Not ccHwnd = 0 Then
                Dim cccHwnd As Integer = Win32.FindWindowEx(ccHwnd, Nothing, "Tedit", Nothing)
                If Not cccHwnd = 0 Then
                    Win32.SetForegroundWindow(cccHwnd)
                    SendKeys.Send("990")
                Else
                    MessageBox.Show("Bitte Starte erst die Programme")
                End If
            Else
                MessageBox.Show("Bitte Starte erst die Programme")
            End If
        Else
            MessageBox.Show("Bitte Starte erst die Programme")

        End If
        Win32.SetForegroundWindow(HwndInfo)
        SendKeys.Send("999")
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("Bitte Starte erst die Programme")
    End If
    'Startbutton Klicken

    Dim HwndFunktion As Integer = Win32.FindWindowEx(Hwnd, Nothing, "TGroupBox", "Funktion")
    If Not HwndFunktion = 0 Then
        Dim cHwnd As Integer = Win32.FindWindowEx(HwndFunktion, Nothing, "TButton", "S T A R T")
        If Not cHwnd = 0 Then
            Win32.SetForegroundWindow(cHwnd)
            Win32.SendMessage(cHwnd, Win32.WM_SETFOCUS, 0, 0)
            Win32.SendMessage(cHwnd, Win32.WM_NCLBUTTONDBLCLK, 0, 0)
            Win32.SendMessage(cHwnd, Win32.WM_NCLBUTTONDBLCLK, 0, 0)
            Win32.SendMessage(cHwnd, Win32.WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN, 0, 0)
            Win32.SendMessage(cHwnd, Win32.WM_SETTEXT, 0, "6")
        Else
            MessageBox.Show("Bitte Starte erst die Programme")
        End If
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("Bitte Starte erst die Programme")
    End If

End Sub
```

To the Program itself: It runs on an old test bench, on win 7.
I think it depends on .net 3.5 but i don't have detailed information about it.
As a test, i filled a textbox with my code and even changed the label of the button. Just the click function doesn't work.

First I tried in with mouse positioning, now directly with the handles.
It doesn't work either way.

Please remember, the code works fine on a few tested Programs (except the one I  need it for).

Comment: Is it throwing any exceptions, is it showing the `Bitte Starte erst die Programme` messagebox , or is `cHwnd` found correctly but the receiving program is just not processing the sendmessage?

Comment: Thank you for your response, it dosn't throw any exceptions, it is found correctly, you can even see that the button is focused.

Comment: why are you sending a double click `WM_NCLBUTTONDBLCLK`...is it possible the double click is being processed differently by the receiving program?

Comment: i tried all of these declarations individually, just to get sure. i just wanted to show you what i've already tested.

Comment: Try sending just a `WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN` and `WM_NCLBUTTONUP` or try pressing the enter button once the button has focus `SendMessage(cHwnd, WM_KEYDOWN, VK_RETURN, 0)`

Comment: I already tried  WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN and WM_NCLBUTTONUP. I will try the enter button. thank you

Comment: I tried the enter button unfortunatly it doesn't work either.i noticed something, when I send the "space" button it appears(visualy) like the button got clicked, but the receiving programm doesn't start it's function. really strange behavior.

Comment: if you manually tab thru controls till it gives the button focus then hit space or enter, that works? And manually left-clicking the mouse also works? If so, I'm not sure what it could be... Another option would be to calculate the position of the button on the screen based on the program's window position and then move the mouse using `SetCursorPos` and simulating a mouse click with the `mouse_event` api

Comment: if I manually tab thru till my desired button is focused, and I press Enter it does nothing. When I press Space it seems visually that the button is pressed, but the function doesn't start. it is the same behaviour as programmatically. I already tried the mousemoving and the mouse_event without succes.The button only seem to run the code when I move my mouse per hand und click manually. I'm helpless...

Comment: It's possible the function for the button is triggered by only one specific event: MouseDown, MouseUp, or MouseClick. If you manually use your mouse and press the left button but don't release it then move the mouse away, does the function still trigger?

Comment: Use SendInput API call instead of SendMessage.

Comment: Is it possible for you to send me a working example?